# Perform action upon yyparse() call?

Tags: c, linux, compiler-construction, ipc, bison

I'm developing a script language along with a C API so that C programs can interface with my language. It's based on LUA's stack approach. However, I am encountering some problems with synchronization between both modules...

On my init function on the API, I start a thread that makes a system call to my interpreter, so that it will be ready to receive the commands I want it to perform. I also create 2 semaphores so that I can (in theory) sync my API with the interpreter module. I need the operations to be done in the following sequence: Initialise Interpreter -> API sends command -> Interpreter does said command -> Wait for new command.

Here's the main function of the interpreter:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) { 

extern FILE *yyin;

char *semRead = "/canRead";
char *semSend = "/canSend";

sem_t *canRead;
sem_t *canSend;

//this part is just so that my code will be coming through a pipe 
//created by me, instead of stdin
if(argc == 1)
    yyin = stdin;
else if(argc == 2){

    suppress = 1;

    if(strcmp(argv[1], "-s") == 0){

        char *source = "/tmp/colliPipe";
        mkfifo(source, 0666);

        yyin = fopen(source, "w+");
    }
    else{
        printf("Error: unknown option %s\n", argv[1]);
        return -1;
    }
}
else if(argc > 2){
    printf("Error: too many parameters\n");
    return -2;
}
#if YYDEBUG == 1
    extern int yydebug;
    yydebug = 1;
#endif

initTables(); //Initializing symbol tables  

if(!suppress){
    printf("Colli 0.0.1 - 2014");
    printf(">> ");
}

canRead = sem_open(semRead, O_CREAT, 0644, 0);
canSend = sem_open(semSend, O_CREAT, 0644, 0);

sem_post(canSend);

yyparse();

return 0; 
}
```

Thing is: when I create my thread, I have no guarantee that my parser will be ready to receive my input. `sem_post(canSend)` is used to signal that the parser should be ready to get said input, but it's not working because the OS can decide to swap processes after the post, but before `yyparse()`.

Question is: Can I make sure that the parser is ready to parse BEFORE posting to the semaphore?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone is wondering how, I solved it...

Just decided to create a thread to call `yyparse()`, allowing me to put the sem_post after its creation... It seems to work just fine.